# SOAP faultcode env:Client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client, fault

I'm connecting to a webservice, but i'm getting the following XML formatted SOAP Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

and the following JAVA exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Internal Error
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.envioDocumentoTransporte(Unknown Source)
    at at.ws.proxy.DocumentosTransporteProxy.register(DocumentosTransporteProxy.java:79)
```

I need to know if there is a problem on my side or on the server side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ask the service provider what went wrong. The error message does say that this is a error by client, but that could even be just copy-pasted code, as long as it doesn't specify anything.

Also look at your request if anything is out of place.

Comment: I already did that (ask the service provider). I just want to be sure that the problem is on their side...

Comment: The problem was the Service Definition (WSDL) that had incorrect information in the wsdl:binding and wsdl:service sections.