# Error when posting to HTTPS endpoint using Apache Proxy

Tags: jquery, apache, ssl, https, proxy

I’m running into some issues trying to post to a HTTPS endpoint while using Apache’s proxy module.  Posts to a HTTP endpoint work fine.  I’m pretty new to Apache configuration, so I’m hoping one of you may have some insight as to what I’m doing wrong.  Google hasn't helped me much with this particular issue.  An example of a thread I've already read is (I don't have enough reputation to post more links):

- [SOAP faultcode env:Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854681/soap-faultcode-envclient)

  - I've verified that a soap request works via SoapUI, so it doesn't appear that there is anything wrong with the service I'm trying to access.

Example endpoint of sever website is hosted on, also the proxy: http://websiteAndProxyServer.com

Example endpoint to Post to: https://secureServer.com/AccessManagerSOAP

Here is the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

HTTP -> Proxy -> HTTPS

The proxy allows me to get around cross-domain request issues.

Apache version: 2.2.21

jQuery post request:

```
var url = "http://websiteAndProxyServer.com/idm/AccessManagerSOAP";
        $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'POST',
                data: loginRequest,
                success: createUserAndAuthenticateSuccess,
                error: createUserAndAuthenticateError
       });
```

Relevant Apache configuration in httpd.conf:

```
#=============mod-proxy==================
#       UnComment the proxy_module, proxy_balancer_module & proxy_ajp_module below to
#       use ModProxy for enabling different JSessionID cookie names to be provided.

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyPass /remote/ http://nonRelatedServer.net:8082/
ProxyPass /idm/ https://secureServer.com/
```

Relevant Apache configuration in httpd-ssl.conf

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
#  ServerName websiteAndProxyServer.com
#   ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
   ErrorLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/apache2/logs/localhost/error_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400"
   CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /usr/local/apache2/logs/localhost/access_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400" vcombined2
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteOptions inherit

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
#SSLEnable  #I get an error if this is un-commented
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
#   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite DEFAULT:!ADH::RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:+eNULL

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
#SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/server-dsa.crt

SSLProxyCACertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/iam.crt
#SSLProxyCACertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
```

I’ve tried getting certs form the destination URL and referencing them by my iam.crt reference above.  That didn’t seem to make a difference.

With the above configuration, I get back the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Note that the HTTP code I get back is 200.  When I send a similar request to the above endpoint via SoapUI, I get a success back, so it has to be something to do with my configuration or permissions.  Is there something else to the configuration that I’m missing?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was no issue with my configuration at all.  Instead, my soap request was malformed.  I didn't include the request inside a soap envelope.  After making this change, the request came back fine.

Old request:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes"?>
<accountCreateRequestxmlns="http://schemaSite.com/schema/">
       <namespaceId>50000003</namespaceId>
       <emailAddress>7e837231-7a3d-495a@g88.net</emailAddress>
       <password>infdafs</password>
       <generateLoginName>false</generateLoginName>
       <loginName>7e837231-7a3d-495a@g88.net</loginName>
       <securityQuestion></securityQuestion>
       <securityAnswer></securityAnswer>
       <securityLevel>LOW</securityLevel>
</accountCreateRequest>
```

New request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://schemaSite.com/messages/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:accountCreateRequest>
         <mes:namespaceId>50000003</mes:namespaceId>
         <mes:emailAddress>7e837231-7a3d-495a@g88.net</mes:emailAddress>
         <mes:password>!fdsuit01</mes:password>
         <mes:generateLoginName>false</mes:generateLoginName>
         <mes:loginName>7e837231-7a3d-495a@g88.net</mes:loginName>
         <mes:securityQuestion></mes:securityQuestion>
         <mes:securityAnswer></mes:securityAnswer>
         <mes:securityLevel>LOW</mes:securityLevel>
      </mes:accountCreateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```